# Cookie expiration date won't change.

Tags: javascript, cookies, expired-cookies

I'm trying to create a cookie and set an expiration date but it stays as "Session". I'm using Google Chrome.

What am I doing wrong?

document.cookie = "savedTests=[{'id':12345678}];expires=" + date.toUTCString() + ";path=/" ;

Comment: Not sure this is the source of your problem but you don't need the single quotes around `id` in your cookie value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This, Changed some layout for better understanding :

```
var cookieName = 'savedTests';
var cookieValue = [
{'id':12345678}
];
var cookieString = JSON.stringify(cookieValue);

var addDays = 2;
var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setTime(newDate.getTime() + (addDays*24*60*60*1000));
var expiresInTime = "expires="+ newDate.toUTCString();
document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieString + ";" + expiresInTime + ";path=/";
```

Result :
[image: Result]

Comment: Breaking it all down to steps like this worked. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. :)